# about the use of verb 'anfragen' : can it take object word?

Tags: verb, expression, objects

I saw in the dictionary the verb `anfragen` is vi. (intransitive verb, verb that doesn't take object word.) Someone asked me

A. Darf ich Sie anfragen?

But I think it should be fixed to

B. Darf ich Sie etwas fragen?  or
C. Darf ich Ihnen über etwas anfragen?

Is my understanding correct?

And I thought, when the speaker and listener know what the topic is,

D. Darf ich Ihnen anfragen?

can also be said. Is D ok?

I'm almost sure my understanding is correct, but just to make sure, please tell me which is wrong, which is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Darf ich Sie anfragen?

That one is correct. You are asking whether you may come back to this person right now.

> Darf ich Sie etwas fragen?

Also correct, but it doesn't mean the same thing. *Anfragen* specifically means asking for supplies or an appointment.

> Darf ich Ersatzteile anfragen?

*May I inquire replacement parts?*

> <s>Darf ich Ihnen über etwas anfragen?</s>
>
> <s>Darf ich Ihnen anfragen?</s>

Both incorrect because the dative object to *anfragen* is (as usual) the person who receives something.

> Soll ich Ihnen einen Termin in der Werkstatt anfragen?

*Should I get you an appointment at the garage?*

Comment: Ich kenne _Darf ich Sie anfragen?_ nicht in der Bedeutung "whether you may come back to this person right now" (sondern, wie es auch help-info.de in seiner Antwort erklärt, nur mit Bezug auf einen Sänger/Autor/..., den man für einen Auftritt/eine Lesung buchen will). Das letzte Beispiel _(jmdm. einen Termin in der Werkstatt anfragen)_ ist mir überhaupt nicht geläufig. In _Harras et al._, Handbuch deutscher Kommunikationsverben, Teil 1, 2004, Eintrag "anfragen" ist eine solche Verwendung auch nicht verzeichnet. Eventuell regional?

Comment: I see. I later found in a separate item in the dictionary thay we can use `jn (bei jm) nach et.  anfragen` as ask someone for something as a transitive verb. Now I can understand your answer and how to use the word. Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to ask this short question `(A: Darf ich Sie anfragen?)` in connection with the preparation of a lecture event i.e. ask for possible speakers.

Fixing A in this context to B, C or D ist wrong.

C and D are wrong as German.

In another context question B in itself is a correct sentence.

Comment: @MarzipanHerz - thanks. Edited my answer.